# blender will not render any videos

Tags: rendering

I'm having an issue with blender where whenever I try to render as any sort of video, instead of showing up as an mp4 or whatever file type I chose, it will show up as a mystery file that cannot be opened. This issue started recently and randomly: I was always able to render perfectly fine before and I used the exact same settings now that I did then. [image: what the file looks like in a folder] [image: what the file looks like when you try to open it] not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. Here are the export settings I am using: [image: export settings 1] [image: export settings 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have turned off file extensions in blender, which includes not only the frame numbering but the vital ".mp4" Filename Extension. The file you rendered is an mp4 file, but it doesn't have a "label" so to speak. I recommend turning on "show filename extensions" in File Explorer to avoid confusion in the future, but to fix the issue at hand:

- Turn on "file extensions" in blender for a fix to all future renders.
  OR
- Type ".mp4" at the end of your filename in blender as a fix to all future renders.

Plus, you can:

- Rename the existing rendered file, adding ".mp4" at the end, which will save it. :D

Note: upon the renaming, the added ".mp4" change may be hidden by Explorer without the "show filename extensions" turned on, but it probably did work.